# I have an error with audiotracks on javascript, an error with "lenght"

Tags: javascript, html

I have a video with multitrack audio, i need change this languages in html

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
    at (index):103
(anonymous) @ (index):103

Comment: <video id="video" controls width='100%' height='100%' poster=''>
    <source src='the.mp4' type='video/mp4'>
    <track kind="captions" src="Dogmaespanol.vtt" label="español" default>
    <p class='vjs-no-js'>
      To view this video please enable JavaScript, and consider upgrading to a web browser that
      <a href='https://videojs.com/html5-video-support/' target='_blank'>supports HTML5 video</a>
    </p>

    </video>

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">  
var video = document.getElementById("video");
for (var i = 0; i < video.audioTracks.length; i += 1) {
  console.log(video.audioTracks[i].language)
  console.log(video.audioTracks[i].label)
}
// enable one
video.audioTracks[2].enabled = true;
</script>

Comment: Don't modify your question with comments; **edit** the question. Code is unreadable in comments.

Comment: From what you have  posted in the comment, looks like you are using a property that is a) not supported in chrome at all, and b) not enabled in Firefox by default - so, unless you're using Edge, Opera or Safari, then your code will not possibly work at all ... see [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/audioTracks) specifically the Browser Compatibility table at the bottom of that page

Comment: i think your forloop should be for (var i = 0; i < video.audioTracks.length; i++)

Comment: @aaronlilly ... `i++` vs `i+=1` (in this context, there is absolutely no difference between the two) is hardly going to be the issue if `video.audioTracks` is undefined :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seeing as the comment is being ignored

> According to **[documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/audioTracks#Browser_compatibility)**

`HTMLMEdiaElement.audioTracks` is only available in

- Edge
- Safari
- Opera
- Firefox (if specifically enabled)

It's not at all available in Chrome and most likely not in Internet Exploder

At a guess, you are using one of the 3 browsers this property is **NOT** available in

Which is why it is `undefined`

Comment: I should add neither Chrome nor Firefox, as of today, implement either of `MediaSource.audioTracks`, `MediaSource.videoTracks`, `HTMLMediaElement.audioTracks`, or `HTMLMediaElement.videoTracks`. Without enabling these features by the user / system administrator on the client side, that is.

Comment: @amn - Yes, 2 years is a LOOONG time in browser development